# Display primary : foreign key relationships in Visio database diagram

Tags: database, microsoft-visio, uml, microsoft-visio-2007, erd

I've created a Database Model relationship diagram in Visio with tables and relationships.  However, I can't find any way to automatically display the Primary Key :: Foreign Key relationship in the diagram.  The only workaround I can find is to insert a text box on top of the relationship and manually type it in ([Database Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLvQB.jpg)).  Or you can kinda do the same by naming the relationship and displaying that.  However, both of these are very manual and time-consuming.  Plus I've already defined the relationship, so why should I have to type it in again!?